# No module named 'google trans'

Tags: python, nlp, importerror

I've got warning while installing the `pip googletrans`.

The warning says in the picture:

[image: The warning says in the picture]

Does it affect my code? the error says "No module named 'google trans'?

error-screenshot:

[image: error-screenshot]

```
from tkinter import *
import googletrans
import textblob
from tkinter import ttk, messagebox

root = Tk ()
root.title('Codemy.com - Translator')
root.geometry("880x300")

def translate_it():
    pass

# Text Boxes
original_text = Text(root, height=10, width=40)
original_text.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=20, padx=10)

translate_button = Button(root, text="Translate!", font=("Helvetica", 24), command=translate_it)
translate_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)

translated_text = Text(root, height=10, width=40)
translated_text.grid(row=0, column=2, pady=20, padx=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Do you have more than one version of python installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the directory of the googletrans module and make sure it's within the list.
You can check the directories that python reads with:

```
import sys
sys.path
```

You can add the directory of googletrans with:

```
sys.path.append('/Users/name/Documents')
```

Comment: I'm sorry i don't understand, can you elaborate or more detailed? I'm sorry i'm just a beginner in python @quagrain

Comment: Ok. I'm not too sure about my solution but I understand Python modules have a sort of list of directories that Python refers to when you call a module. It first checks the directory containing the script you run, then a certain list of directories defined by Python. If your module was installed outside these directories it probably won't work. 

Refer to this part of the documentation for more info: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=modules#:~:text=6.1.2.-,The%20Module%20Search%20Path,-%C2%B6

Comment: `sys.path` will show you the list of these directories while `sys.path.append('')` will allow you to add a new directory to the default. `sys.path` will show you the directories as a list so you could work with it as a list to append new directories. I hope I was able to clarify. If not I'm sure the documentation will do a good job with that.

Comment: how will i make the googletrans in the right directories? @quagrain

Comment: do you know where the googletrans module is on your computer?

Comment: im sorry no @quagrain

Comment: you could search for it in your file explorer. then right click it to check the properties. you'll see the directory in the form of  'C:/...' If you're on a mac you could try the finder and right click to get info.